# Voting system with unequal votes

Tags: javascript, database

I intend to implement voting system in my webapp (reactJs, flux, nodejs + express server)

Many users (thousands) can vote and their votes are unequal. From 1 till 100. They can vote for or against. I need to have arithmetic average for all the votes in my database. I have thousands pages with voting systems. How can i implement it?
I guess, i could store all the votes from each page in one cell of database table. 
When i will need to render the average vote on frontend, i will retrieve json object like that:

```
{ page1: [1,22,5,7,32,...~1000 more numbers] }
```

and use js on client-side to calculate the arithmetic average.

Is it a good idea? Maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case won't lose you the relationship between whom voted what?

I'd rather prefer to store votes on a many to many table referencing the user voting, the element voted and the value of the vote.

When you want to show the average, a quick Sql query can return you the aritmethic average.

But additionally you can know a lot of info more on user vote behaviour (users that always votes max or min values, users that do so on certain items while do the opposite on others, users that vote some items but not vote others... and an immense etc).

With that data in mind you can implement a more reliable vote value than a simple average... but this is a completely different matter.

Answer (score 2):

If you store all the votes from each page as you described, you may run into trouble tracking who has voted and who has not. I would suggest a simple map table.

```
Table 1:
UserID (int), NumberOfVotes (int)

Table2:
PageID (int), UserID (int), ForOrAgainst (binary 1=for, 0=against)
```

Then to count votes you can simply join the tables and SUM(NumberOfVotes) for, and subtract SUM(NumberOfVotes) against a given PageID.

[Here's an SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01dcc/1/0) that sums the votes FOR a given page. Note that you'd need a 2nd query (or two subqueries) to also get the votes AGAINST.